# NASM. НЕ работает простой код

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

Вопрос следующий: Почему не работает следующий код:

```
section .text
    global _start
_start:

    mov edx, 5
    mov ecx, 'ABCDE'
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80

    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

Даже если в edx положить 1, а в ecx 65 (A), то "А" не будет выведено. Почему так?
Ос Ubuntu

Comment: Потому что в ecx ожидается адрес буфера в памяти, где находится строка, а вы пытаетесь строку запихнуть в регистр.

Comment: Как тогда вывести, например букву А, передав в есх 65, без использования сторонних хранилищ? Или так же эту строку?

Comment: 1 - Нет, то что вы записали текст в кавычках - это еще не означает, что автоматически где-то в памяти появится эта строка. 2 - без понятия, я не пишу на ассемблере под Linux.